Are there any org-agenda commands to delete log entries?
Sometimes I clock in/out of the wrong task and I end up with empty clock lines, which are just noise. Is there any function to delete these from the agenda, without having to open the log book?

Not that I know of - but you should be able to do what you want with ordinary search-and-replace commands.
